Nokia 7.1 files encrypting, but not decrypting after adding microSDXC
I have a Nokia 7.1 that had some existing photos, videos and other misc files.
I added a micro SDXC card and accepted the option to use it as internal storage, with the option of migrating the existing data.
The phone completed the process and still works, however the photos and videos etc. are unable to be opened.
Interestingly, new photos can be accessed for a brief period of time before becoming inaccessible.
The files show a high entropy when anaylsing them with jpeg recovery tools.
This leads me to believe that the files are being encrypted, however they are not being decrypted.
The device has not been reset, this happened without taking the SD card out of the phone.
The fact that files are being encrypted makes me think the device could still have the keys required to decrypt the data.
Is there anything I could try to decrypt the files based on this scenario?
EDIT:
Just to add some clarifications based on comments:

The phone still works which makes it unlikely to be a bad card
There's no custom encryption software installed
Malware is unlikely, the process of using the card as internal storage led to the issue

EDIT 2
Any possible solutions for me to try would be most welcome

How large is the sd-card and how many GB have you migrated to the sd-card? Are you sure the card is genuine? Depending where you buy it there is a chance that cheap sd-cards are fake cards, they have much less flash memory as they claim to have.

@Robert the card is 256 GB and I moved about ~70GB in total.  That thought had crossed my mind, however I figured the phone wouldn't be working at all as all the system files would be affected in the same way.
I bought it from the SanDisk store on Amazon.

Agree, that makes in unlikely to be a hardware problem. If the files really get encrypted the question is if this a malfunction if Android OS or of a third party app. Especially that it doesn't happen immediately may be an indicator that this is not caused by the system itself. Do you have some custom encryption app installed? Alternatively a ransomware app would also be a possibility however modern malware apps of that type wouldn't encrypt the whole file for speeding up the process..

@Robert thanks for your reply, there's no custom encryption app installed and ransomware is not likely, this issue only occurred when the card was used as internal storage.

I have actually seen this happen once before... I am pretty sure it was my son's Nokia 6.1 that did essentially the same thing but that was like 4-5 (?) years ago. We never were able to recover anything off of it, luckily most of it was in Google Photos, but the only answer was factory reset, then it worked as expected. My best guess is somehow the encryption key got corrupted or something, and resetting the device cleared it up. He continued to use that microSD card in that device for the remainder of it's life without incident.
